# Clustering semantically similar with NLP

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a corpus of 2000 competencies from multiple frameworks having a dataset like -

```
Framework    |   Category      |   Competency
```

where, the `Category` names are different (but in most cases mappable) across frameworks, and
the `Competencies` are in the form of sentences or phrases (<50 words).

Using NLP, I want to cluster all the semantically similar competencies across frameworks together into a new framework that has `~200 core competencies`, such that when I come across any new frameworks, the competencies are clustered and mapped to these core competencies of the new framework.

I am fairly certain that this requires a K-Means and/or Agglomerative clustering approach. I want to know if someone has solved a similar challenge, and if so, what process and tools did they use and how satisfactory were the results?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this can be solved using clustering algorithm (there are many viable, so no reason to stick to K-Means only). The key problem is to establish some form of a metric. You can do this by using [word embeddings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-word-embedding-using-word2vec/) and cosine similarity metrics (e.g. [sklearn's cosine pairwise](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)).

Centroids of the 200 clusters are going to be the ones to compare against should you want to extend or map another set of competencies.

Of course, this is a gross oversimplification of the problem, where there are nuances starting from the selection of embedding type and its size, through the approach to finding the best centroids and / or most similar ones when extending the list. But any of these would require another [well-posed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to respond.

Comment: thanks! Can you detail the process you might follow and the best suited algorithms for this problem?

Comment: I can but it does not fit the rules for proper questions/answers on StackOverflow (as I suggested in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and feed back.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import distance
    
words = "kitten belly squooshy merley best eating google feedback face extension impressed map feedback google eating face extension climbing key".split(" ") #Replace this line
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:* %s" % (exemplar, cluster_str))
```

Result:

```
 - *squooshy:* squooshy
 - *feedback:* feedback
 - *extension:* extension
 - *impressed:* impressed
 - *google:* google
 - *eating:* climbing, eating
 - *face:* face, map
 - *key:* belly, best, key, kitten, merley
```